# How can I set the height of a v-card independently from the content, without setting a static height?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js, spacing, vuetifyjs3

I have a Vuetify 3 application with a header, a navigation drawer and a `v-main` with a `v-card` inside where my `router-view` is placed.

My problem is that the card gets bigger when the content takes more space than the 100%. But if the content is bigger, it should be scrollable inside the `v-card-text` without changing the size.

So: how can I set the height of the `v-card` (or `v-card-text`?) independently from the content, without setting a static height (like `height="300px"`)?

```html
<template>
  <v-app id="app">
    <Header></Header>
    <NavigationDrawer></NavigationDrawer>
    <v-main class="flex-grow-1">
      <v-container class="cardContainer pa-0 pr-4 pb-4" fluid>
        <v-card id="vcard" height="100%">
          <v-card-text style="max-height: inherit;">
            <router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<style>
.cardContainer {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuetify: scroll list inside card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848932/vuetify-scroll-list-inside-card)

Comment: @beerwin No. My card can't have a fixed height like `height="200px"`.

Comment: Did you consider CSS `max-height` and the `scrollable` directive for `v-card`>

Comment: `max-height` will allow v-card to grow to that value and then the content would have to scroll afterwards (you won't have a fixed height).

Comment: @beerwin `max-height: inherit;` and `max-height: 100%;` doesn't change anything. To set <X>px as max-width isn't possible. (static)

Comment: `max-height: inherit` does nothing, `max-height: 100%`:  what you relate 100% to? for `max-height`, you need to specify a fixed value. If the element growth fits in this value, it will grow until the height reaches this value (hence `max-`).